# Parsing selected file to array in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, deserialization, filereader

I am trying to parse a selected file into an object array in Angular 7.

HTML where I select the file:

```
<div class="form-group" *ngIf="import">
  <label for="file">Choose backup file</label>
  <input type="file" id="file" (change)="handleFileInput($event.target.files)">
</div>
```

I am already able to log the the values from the file using this code snippet:

```
fileToUpload: File = null;
handleFileInput(files: FileList) {
    this.fileToUpload = files.item(0);
    this.parseFile();
}

parseFile() {
  const fileReader = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = (e) => {
    console.log(fileReader.result);
  }

  fileReader.readAsText(this.fileToUpload);
}
```

The file always is a json file containing an array of objects like this:

```
[
    {"Test": "ValueA", "Value": "SomeStringA"},
    {"Test": "ValueB", "Value": "SomeStringB"},
    ...
]
```

My goal is to deserialize into an object array `ObjectA[]` for the following object:

```
export interface ObjectA {
    Test: string;
    Value: string;
}
```

Can someone help me how to go on with filereader to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FileReader) takes a string, parses it and returns an object. You can use it to parse your file.

You could do something like that:

```
async parseFile(): Promise<ObjectA[]> {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise<ObjectA[]>((resolve) => {
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(fileReader.result));
        }

        fileReader.readAsText(this.fileToUpload);
    });
}
```

Of course, my solution lacks error handling, but you get the gist. Below is a working code snippet demonstrating my solution (minus the type casting).

```js
async function uploadFiles(files)  {
  for(const file of files) {
      const parsedObject = await parse(file);
      // Do stuff with your object
  }
}

async function parse(file) {
    const fileReader = new FileReader();

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        fileReader.onload = (e) => {
            resolve(JSON.parse(fileReader.result));
        }

        fileReader.readAsText(file);
    });
}
```

```html
<div>
    <input type="file" onchange="uploadFiles(this.files)" />
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. your solution isnt working and it lacks a necessary condition `if (typeof fileReader.result === 'string')`.

Comment: As I mentioned, my solution lacks error handling. What about it doesn't work exactly? I added a working code snippet.

Comment: this quite the same code as posted above from me, the only difference is the using of JSON.parse() to display its output to console.log

Comment: You say you are trying to parse a file into an object. That's exactly what my method does though. I don't think I quite understand your question. (Of course, the snippet is in JavaScript and therefore doesn't have the typing, but the snippet before should do exactly the same.)

Comment: This code works like a charm. It parses your input string in Json, then the Promise type casts it to "ObjectA" type. Here is a stackblitz working with this solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-92kjsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts